# How can I replace HTML in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, html, wordpress, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1054

I want to find and replace (or more accurately, append) some HTML in one of my MySQL database fields, where the field contains a specific string of text.

I can successfully find the relevant records using this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%some phrase%'
```

This query returns all the records I want to append HTML to.

So I try the following query to append the HTML I want to use:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%some phrase%'
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '</strong></a>', '</strong></a>
<strong>Some additional piece of text</strong></p>')
```

But an error is returned:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = INSERT(post_content, '&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/a&gt;​', '&lt;/stro' at line 4
```

I presume it doesn't like how I've formatted my HTML, but how should it be formatted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are trying to execute two different queries. My guess is that you need to execute the following one:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '</strong></a>', '</strong></a>
<strong>Some additional piece of text</strong></p>') 
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%some phrase%'
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks - I see what I was trying to do there :-)

Answer (score 4):

look on [UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) , need to be like

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '</strong></a>', '</strong></a>
<strong>Some additional piece of text</strong></p>')
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%some phrase%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the select as an inner query? (assuming

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, '</strong></a>', '</strong></a>
<strong>Some additional piece of text</strong></p>') 

WHERE id in (SELECT id
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%some phrase%')
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the content you're trying to replace. However, the way I see it, you construct your update query the wrong way: You put a `SELECT` right before an `UPDATE` query, probably expecting the `UPDATE` would only touch the `SELECT`ed rows.

I think what you want is this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts 
    SET post_content = REPLACE(
        post_content,
        '</strong></a>',
        '</strong></a><strong>Some additional piece of text</strong></p>'
    )
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%some phrase%'
```

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, guys :-)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL >= 5.5 provides XML functions to solve your issue.
You can combine `ExtractValue`, `UpdateXML` and `REPLACE` functions.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html